# Problem enabling dnsmasq

Tags: 20.04, dnsmasq

I work on Ruby on Rails project which uses some subdomains and custom domains. I have installed dnsmasq server and added this to the starting of the file:

```
address=/xyz.test/127.0.0.1
address=/xyzsites.test/127.0.0.1
address=/abc.test/127.0.0.1
address=/ab.test/127.0.0.1
```

But that doesn't work automatically. Each time my laptop boots I have to set IP address in `resolv.conf` file like this:

```
nameserver 192.168.xx.x
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

And it starts working. I know the file gets reset on each reboot or `NetworkManager` restart but I am using a desktop PC too which has a similar configuration I have never faced issues on that. The default configuration of this file is on both the PC and laptop is:

```
search dlink.router
# this is set to the router's IP address and not the system's IP address 
nameserver 192.168.xx.x
```

With the same file, it works on my PC but not the laptop. I have tried installing `resolvconf` but that didn't work instead my internet stopped working and I had to remove it.

I also tried setting this in `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`:

```
[main]
dns=dnsmasq
```

but then my internet stopped working again and I had to set it to `default`.

What could I do to make it work automatically or what could I check to match it to my other PC's configuration or if anyone has any other suggestions?

**Note:** My `/etc/hosts` file has some entries like this:

```
127.0.0.1   xyz.test
127.0.0.1   *.xyz.test
127.0.0.1   us.xyz.test
127.0.0.1   secure.xyz.test
127.0.0.1   123.xyz.test
127.0.0.1   xyzsites.test
```

I am not sure if this would matter.

Comment: What distro/version are you using (see `lsb_release -a`). I suspect your problem is that youve got two resolvers working, have a look at systemd-resolved.

Comment: @pbhj Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS and the `systemd-resolved.service` is dead

Comment: I am running 20.04, `dnsmasq` is not installed and `systemd-resolved` is running.  I would check the logs in order to determine what could be killing the process.  I am also linking the information for systemd-resolved, perhaps something in there may also help.  You can edit your question with the logs if you would like help from the community.  https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man8/systemd-resolved.service.8.html

Comment: I also searched the community and I found an answer related to dnsmasq for 20.04.  If this doesn't help I would keep searching, there are several related questions: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1291673/failed-to-configure-networkmanager-to-use-dnsmasq?rq=1